# How to show a downloading activity for firebase storage download

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress, firebase-storage

I have an app that uploads and shows images. I have found when I'm not on wifi, it takes some time for the image to download. I want to improve my UX so i would like to have a download activity indicator when I am downloading an image.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

[[[FIRStorage storage] referenceForURL:profileURL] dataWithMaxSize:INT64_MAX
                                                                        completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                                                            if (error) {
                                                                                NSLog(@"Error downloading: %@", error);
                                                                                return;
                                                                            }
                                                                            NSString *dataType=[self contentTypeForImageData:data];
                                                                            if (dataType) {
                                                                            [_imageCache setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data] forKey:uid];
                                                                            }
                                                                            myIcon.image =
                                                                            [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                                                                        }];
            });
```

This is how i download the image and cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thing 1: No need to use the additional queue, we already perform the download on a background thread, so it won't block your UI.

Thing 2: You want to do something like:

```
// Upload file and metadata to the object 'images/mountains.jpg'
FIRStorageUploadTask *uploadTask = [storageRef putFile:localFile metadata:metadata];

// Start the upload progress UI

[uploadTask observeStatus:FIRStorageTaskStatusProgress handler:^(FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *snapshot) {
  // Update the progress UI with the progress
}];

[uploadTask observeStatus:FIRStorageTaskStatusSuccess handler:^(FIRStorageTaskSnapshot *snapshot) {
  // Remove the progress UI
}];
```

Consider [`MBProgressHub`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) for your spinner.